# $B_t$ has same law of $-B_t$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_t$ a real brownian motion. On the literature there are several proofs of the fact that $Y_t = -B_t$ is still a brownian motion.

> I was trying to show myself that $B_t$ and $Y_t$ have the same law.

---

We know that both $B_t$ and $Y_t$ are centered Gaussian random
   variables, hence they have the same law iff they have the same
   covariance matrix $\Gamma$.

Then $$Cov(Y_t,Y_s) = E[Y_t Y_s] - 0 = E[(-B_t)(-B_s)] = E[B_t B_s] = s \wedge t$$

Now, since $Cov(B_s,B_t) = s \wedge t$ holds for any brownian motion, the covariance matrix is the same, and hence $B_t$ and $-B_t$ have  the same law

Comment: This is fine. There is a typo in the second equality.

Comment: It's fine now,right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Comment: I had almost the same question, hope to get an answer since it's a recent one:

From the fact that $-B_t$ has the same law of $B_t$, does then follows that $- \lambda B_t$ and $\lambda B_t$ are both distributed as $N(0, \lambda^2t)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. The only suggestion of improvement I have is that you want to prove that the process $\left(B_t\right)_{t\geqslant 0}$ and $\left(Y_t\right)_{t\geqslant 0}$ have the same law. Therefore, you need to replace the sentence "We know that both $B_t$ and $Y_t$ are centered Gaussian random variable" by "We know that both $\left(B_t\right)_{t\geqslant 0}$ and $\left(Y_t\right)_{t\geqslant 0}$ are centered Gaussian random variable".

Comment: From the fact that $-B_t$ has the same law of $B_t$, does then follows that $- \lambda B_t$ and $\lambda B_t$ are both distributed as $N(0, \lambda^2t)$?